# How to move linebreak separated list to the same line in vim

Tags: vim

I sometimes run into code like this, e.g. after reducing the number of parameters to a function:

```
def foo(
    arg1,
    arg2):

    # do something
```

Breaking up the parameter list in this way might have made sense when there were lots of long arguments, but now I want the text to look like this:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):

    # do something
```

For me, this usually means moving to the start of `arg1`, entering insert mode, and pressing backspace until I've untabbed the parameter, then repeating for `arg2`.

These situations are too small to warrant setting up a macro or even using sed. Is there a key combination in `vim` that I can use to just remove all of the whitespace (including linebreaks) between the opening parenthesis of `foo` and the first letter of `arg1`?

The example is python but this really isn't a language-specific question.

Comment: Why not use `black`? On saving it should get formatted like this

Comment: @yudhiesh Cool, I hadn't heard of that. I was looking for a language-agnostic solution  but `black` is still an interesting suggestion.

Comment: Yeah I use it with [coc-pyright](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For me, this usually means moving to the start of `arg1`, entering insert mode, and pressing backspace until I've untabbed the parameter, then repeating for `arg2`.

Or, more simply, `JxJJ`.

But, as per the comments, using [an external formatter](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a pretty sensible idea.

```
" in after/ftplugin/python.vim
set formatprg=black-3.8\ -q\ -
```

See `:help J`, `:help gq`.